# Unity Anti-aliased Edge Shader with Variable Thickness (does not require standard shaders or post processing)

Tags: unity, shaders

I'm trying to create a coloring-book effect for an edge shader (*not* an outline shader) but having some difficulty creating straight line shaders that don't look badly anti-aliased. (Even before getting to the variable thickness on the lines part)

The solutions I've found seem to reference Vectrosity or post-processing stack. Is such a thing as a shader (not post-processing level) edge shader not possible?

Comment: How do you define the difference between an edge shader and an outline shader?

Comment: Outline is just your typical selection glow type. Edge shader looks more like this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/image-effect-edge-detect-normals-colours-rel.310280/ - but in this example, they use both ImageEffects (post-processing) and also with no line width or anti-alias control @DMGregory

Comment: That type of effect pretty much needs to be implemented as a post effect. The individual fragments you're drawing never know if they're on a local crease or silhouette edge. As far as they can determine, they're just one pixel on an infinite plane. The edge shapes — silhouette edges in particular, but also self-overlaps, arise in image space, so they're easiest to identify in a second pass after the depth/normals of the object have been written into image space.